# PHP - If statement to show a special text on holidays

Tags: php, date, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to find a way to generate a special text in PHP depending on which holiday it is. I was trying if-statement and switch but I cannot figure out the logic of it. Can you please advise how can it be done? The goal is to have two lines of text:

Today is Thursday.

Happy Fat Thursday!

If there is no holiday on a given day, only first line of text should be shown.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE");
$dag = strftime('%A', time());
$datum = strftime('%D', time());

    {
    echo "Idag är det ".$dag."<br>";
    }

switch ($datum)
{
    case ($datum = '01/01/2020'):
        echo "Gott Nytt År";
    break;

    case ($datum = '01/06/2020'):
        echo "Glad Trettondedag Jul";
    break;        

    case ($datum = '02/20/2020'):
        echo "Happy Fat Thursday!";
    break;    

    default:
        echo ' ';
        break;
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if the text was in english.

Comment: `$datum = strftime('%D', time());` returns date like 02/20/20. You should change to `$datum = strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time());`

Comment: *"Happy Fat Thursday"*  - Shouldn't that be "Happy Fat Tuesday"? Seems like something from Mardi Gras.

Comment: Sorry, next time I will write everything in English. Yes, only now I realized the inconsistency with the date. Thanks! BTW, Fat Thursday is celebrated in Poland, I suppose its a version of Mardi Gras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this

I'm not sure why you were using an expression in every `case` but you have already set the variable you are checking against as an argument to `switch`, so you just need to enter the values as the case.

I've also removed the first echo because I have no idea why that was there at all and I've moved it into the `default` catch, meaning that if no other `case` is triggered, the default will fire.

Also, leading on from @Cadu De Castro Alves comment, I changed `$datum` to:

```
$datum = strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time());
```

As the previous pattern you were using would return a two-digit year as opposed to the four-digits your checking for.

You can read more about [switch here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

---

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE");
$dag = strftime('%A', time());
$datum = strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time());

switch ($datum) {
    case '01/01/2020':
        echo "Gott Nytt År";
    break;

    case '01/06/2020':
        echo "Glad Trettondedag Jul";
    break;        

    case '02/20/2020':
        echo "Happy Fat Thursday!";
    break;    

    default:
        echo "Idag är det ".$dag."<br>";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work as expected now. I wrote the first echo because i considered this to be a constant that should be always there and then I wanted to create an exception by using switch-statement. Obviously I misunderstood the nature of switch but now I get it.

Comment: Brilliant - if you can mark this answer as correct it would be appreciated